# Ionic Framework iOS "Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater."

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add iOS as a platform for my app but when I run:
    ionic platform iOS 
I get the error "Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater." I have Xcode 5.1.1 installed which comes with the command-line tools. I have tried:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
but when I run:
    xcodebuild -version
it says I have Xcode version 4.4 installed.

I've been stuck on this for a while now so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you follow these steps? Do you see multiple versions listed? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/SpecifyingCommandLineTools/SpecifyingCommandLineTools.html

Comment: And what path is comes back when you run: which xcodebuild

Comment: Finally got it working. Turns out /usr/bin had two files: xcodebuild and xcodebuild.orig .. xcodebuild.orig was the correct version so I renamed it to xcodebuild and everything works fine. Not sure why this happened but it works now :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome. That's odd but good to know for the future. Cheers.